# window.onbeforeunload performing query

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to perform a post query when the user leaves the page. The code I'm working with is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var used = $('#identifier').val();
    $.post('conversation.php?leave=true',{ud:used});
}
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing here? The result I get in the FF error console is just saying that other non-related functions/variables are not defined (since they are unloading). Any tips or pointers for what I need to fix?

Comment: So is it working or not?

Comment: No, the post to conversation.php?leave=true should yield a database update. It does not.

Comment: instead of making a database call , take some cookie approach..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't make an asynchronous AJAX call in the `beforeunload` event reliably, it'll *very* likely be terminated before it finished, as the browser garbage collects the page.  You *can* make a synchronous call, like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: 'conversation.php?leave=true', 
  data:{ud:used}, 
  async: false
});
```

Please *don't* do this though, as it traps your user in the page for longer than needed and prevents them from leaving, resulting in a negative experience.  Note that this also **locks up the browser** while it executes, `async: false` should be avoided in every case possible.

Comment: @Nick , then what is real use of async:false , is it really useful or used anywhere..

Comment: hmmm...I might consider that if it is the ONLY option just because the query that is made takes ~.006 seconds to perform. http://seewhosoutthere.com/conversation?leave=true

Comment: @ryan , it might not be true in all cases depends up on internet connection , your database load , webserver load etc

Comment: @gov ,yea your right. I just wish there was something I could do. I hate to resort to last resort tactics like that.

Comment: I would have thought `onbeforeunload` is pretty much the only time when an asynchronous AJAX calls *would* be appropriate.

Comment: @lonesomeday - synchronous JAX calls* :)