# JQuery beforeunload event not firing when leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to send an AJAX request when a user leaves my site in order to kill their session. I've done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        $.get("/forceLogout");
    });
});
```

and it works perfectly if I close the tab.  However if I just type google.com in the address bar and press enter, the event does not fire.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4235437/1623811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an asynchronous call at the time the page is being unloaded. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          url: "/forceLogout", 
          async: false
        }); 
    });
});
```